# Links generated in while loop vulnerable to SQL injections

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection, http-get

I have a database where I store data of users and devices. Every user has a list of devices. When the user logs into his account the `php` code below generates a list of the users devices:

```
$query_user="SELECT * FROM devices WHERE users_id = '".$user_id."'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query_user);

// generating device list and ON and OFF device links
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<br><p>". $row["device"] ."</p><a href=on.php?data=" . $row["device"] . ">ON</a><br><a href=off.php?data=" . $row["device"] . ">OFF</a><br>";
}
```

The code also generates a `ON` and `OFF` link so the user can manipulate his devices. When the user click for example `ON` then the following `URL` is passed to the browser:

```
https://.../on.php?data=device23
```

The part of the `on.php` code that handles the URL data:

```
if(isset($_GET["data"]))
{
    $device_name = $_GET["data"];
}

$query_user="UPDATE devices SET status='ON' WHERE device = '".$device_name."'";

mysqli_query($db, $query_user);
```

So my problem here is that this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection, for example someone can type:

```
https://.../on.php?data=device17
```

in the browser and turn the `device17` on.

My question is how the generate `ON` and `OFF` links for a list of devices and pass the data safe to the `on.php` and `off.php` files.

**EDIT:**

My main problem here is how to generate ON and OFF links for every users device (every user has a different number of devices). When the user clicks the ON link of for example device23 (or any other device, initially I don't know the device name, I am getting the device names from the first db query) I have to pass the device name to the on.php file so it can preform the SQL query that updates the device status.

Comment: all the queries shown here are vulnerable to sql injection and another potential issue is there is nothing to stop a user typing in the id of someone else ( of course the complexity of the id might limit this possible line of attack ) For a better user experience you might perhaps consider using ajax to send the ON/OFF updates to the backend script rather than a new page each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double-check that the device belongs to the user as you make the `UPDATE` statement in `on.php`:

```
$query_user = "UPDATE devices SET status='ON' WHERE users_id = ? AND device = ?";
```

That's one problem solved. Now for a couple of other problems.

Notice I have avoided putting the PHP variables directly into the SQL query by concatenation. This is the SQL injection risk, which you identified. The way to solve that is [to use query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query_user);
if ($stmt === false) {
    error_log(mysqli_error($db));
    die("Sorry, there has been a software error");
}
$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $user_id, $device_name);
if ($ok === false) {
    error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($db));
    die("Sorry, there has been a software error");
}
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if ($ok === false) {
    error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($db));
    die("Sorry, there has been a software error");
}
```

It's good practice to check for errors after *every* call to one of the mysqli functions. They return **false** if there's an error, and then it's up to you to check for that, log it so you can troubleshoot later, and terminate the PHP request with a friendly error message.

A final problem is the fact that your code is updating data in a GET request. This is usually recommended to be avoided, because search engines that index your site will follow GET links on a page. If a search engine indexer can view your page of links, it will follow each of them, and thus all devices will be turned ON.

In this case, since turning on a device is limited to the devices for the logged-in user, and the search engine indexer is unlikely to have a valid user recorded in the session, it probably won't be a risk. But you should get into the habit of using POST only when you want to update data.

But you can't make a simple `href` link for a POST request. Therefore you would have to make an anchor tag and use Javascript to make an AJAX POST request, as mentioned in the comment from RamRaider above.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping a user from typing such an url in their browser and doing what the link does, you are creating. That is perfectly valid (and in fact, what the browser does anyway by clicking on that link)

Beside that, yes your script is vurnurable to sql injection. You may want to consider using prepared statements to access your database (https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) and additionally implement some kind of authentication mechanism (like user/password authentication, system one-time-passwords,...)

UPDATE:
The linked (duplicated) question‘s answer seems quite reasonable to prevent sql injection in php.

Comment: My main problem here is how to generate ON and OFF links for every users device (every user has a different number of devices). When the user clicks the ON link of for example device23 (or any othe device, initially i don't know the device name) I have to pass the device name to the on.php file so it can preform the SQL query that updates the device status.

Answer (score 0):

The handler of on/off-request has to make two things:

- checks whether the current request is authorized (with using *$_SESSION*) - is the user has login yet? *Yes* - is success. *No* - is failure.
- updates records (table *devices*) are linked with the current authorized *user_id* only.

And I suggest you start using the [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for sql-statements. It will protect you from [*sql-inject*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.